# Understanding Conditional Ternary Operator Logic in This Code Snippet

Tags: solidity, dapps, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3

```
                    (
                        _zeroForOne
                            ? step.sqrtPriceNextX96 < _sqrtPriceLimitX96
                            : step.sqrtPriceNextX96 > _sqrtPriceLimitX96
                    )
                        ? _sqrtPriceLimitX96
                        : step.sqrtPriceNextX96
```

I am explaining this code, tell me if im right or wrong:

If `_zeroForOne` is true i.e if we selling token0 then `step.sqrtPriceNextX96` is less than
`_sqrtPriceLimitX96`, if false then `step.sqrtPriceNextX96 > _sqrtPriceLimitX96`. Suppose `_zeroForOne` is true but `step.sqrtPriceNextX96` is not less than  `_sqrtPriceLimitX96` then the `()` portion will be false,  then we will get `step.sqrtPriceNextX96` as result.

If `_zeroForOne` is false i.e we are buying token0 then if `step.sqrtPriceNextX96 > _sqrtPriceLimitX96` then the `()` portion will be true and `_sqrtPriceLimitX96` will  be result or if `step.sqrtPriceNextX96` not greater than `_sqrtPriceLimitX96` then the `()` portion will be false and the result will be `step.sqrtPriceNextX96`.

If i am wrong then what is right explanation??

Answer (score 0):

You understood the code correctly.

Here's a simple, step-by-step explanation:

Selling token0 (`_zeroForOne` is **true**):

- If "price is less than limit", result: limit.
- If not, result: price.

Buying token0 (`_zeroForOne` is **false**):

- If "price is greater than limit", result: limit.
- If not, result: price.

Comment: Thanks ......